# Torrent download speed is only a small fraction of web download speed

Tags: download, bittorrent

I have a download speed of around 600-900kB/s, however when I download torrents, I only receive a download speed of around 5kB/s.

This problem does not occur using other broadband connections, such as my friends' houses, where there is the same download speed, torrent or not. Is there some way that I can fix this?

Comment: It could also be an issue of open ports, but it is more likely to be an issue of the ISP throttling your traffic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that your ISP throttles speeds in torrents. Also be sure that the torrent has good number of seeds and keep an eye on the Seed : Leech ratio. For info about seeds and leechers see [this.](https://superuser.com/questions/163920/in-torrent-what-is-seed-feed-peer)

If the particular torrent you are downloaded doesn't have a good number of seeds then you won't be able to get a very high speed when downloading. The speed at which a torrent is downloaded is dependent on the speed of the seeders and nothing else.

But when you download a file from the internet, they are fetched from lot faster servers. Moreover the source of a file when you download from a web server remains the same whereas in torrents you download from multiple sources. When one source stops seeding there will be a temporary drop of speed until the tracer of the torrent will direct you to a new seeder.

Check [this](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/bittorrent.htm) to get more information about them.

Comment: The seed:leech ratio is quite low, yes, but 5kb/s? Really?

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting the exact problem pertaining to slow torrents could just be one simple solution or a combination of multiple options. In any event, look at this checklist of possible issues for slow torrent download speeds.

1. Stop Using Public Trackers, Get Into Private Sites
2. Use a Seedbox
3. Download The Right Torrents
4. Use an HTTPS: Tracker
5. Add More Trackers To The Torrent
6. Ports, Port Forwarding and Firewall Configurations
7. Hack Your Max Half Open TCP Connections
8. Set Proper Upload Speed; BitTorrent Connections
9. Experiment With Alternative BitTorrent Clients
10. Your ISP Blocks or Throttles P2P Traffic
11. Disable PeerGuardian / IP Blocking Software
12. Antivirus Software & BitTorrent Conflicts

Check [here](http://filesharefreak.com/2009/02/23/12-clues-and-solutions-to-why-your-torrents-are-slow) how to solve all of them.

Comment: Wow, that's very detailed. I don't really want to get too deep into torrents. I only really use them because so many sites only have torrent formats but thanks for the answer.